# DRF create object with nested serializers and foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF and I'm trying to create an object which has several foreign keys as well as related objects that will need creating in the process.

Here's what a reduced version of my models looks like:

```
class Race(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='races')
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='races', null=True)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('region'), related_name='races')
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='races')
    timezone = models.ForeignKey(Timezone, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    race = models.ForeignKey(Race, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='events')
```

And then here's my Race serializer:

```
class RaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    type = TypeSerializer(read_only=True)
    events = EventSerializer(many=True)
    country = CountrySerializer()
    region = RegionSerializer(read_only=True)
    timezone = TimezoneSerializer(read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        with transaction.atomic():
            events = validated_data.pop('events', None)
            race = Race(**validated_data)
            race.save()
            for event in events:
                Event.objects.create(race=race, **event)
        return race
```

And my view:

```
class AddRaceView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RaceSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

And here's some test data I'm sending with my POST request:

```
{
    "name": "ABC Marathon",
    "country": {
        "pk": 1,
        "name": "United States"
    },
    "region": {
        "pk": 1,
        "code": "ME"
    },
    "timezone": {
        "pk": 1,
        "code": "EST"
    },
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "Marathon"
        },
        {
            "name": "Half Marathon"
        }
    ]
}
```

So the problem I'm having is passing valid data to the serializer for the foreign keys. I don't want to create new objects for `Type`, `Region`, `Country`, `Timezone`, only pass the appropriate data so the newly created Race object references existing foreign keys correctly.

Here's what I've tried:

1) Not setting `read_only=True` on the foreign key serializers. This attempts to create new objects that I don't want.

2) Setting `read_only=True` on the foreign key serializers (as in the code above). This helps with not attempting to create new `Type`, `Region` etc objects, but drops the respective fields from `validated_data` in the serializer create method. So I have no way to add the existing objects to the Race foreign keys on creation.

3) Using PrimaryKeyForeignField instead of `TypeSerializer`, `RegionSerializer` etc. But then when I use `RaceSerializer` to retrieve race data, I only have a `pk` under `type`, `region` etc and I'd really like to be able to retrieve all fields for the foreign keys.

Can you please advise on what the correct setup would look for something like this? I feel like it's shouldn't be as hard as this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So in the end I solved this by using `RelatedField` instead of separate serializers for every foreign key, with the exception of the nested `EventSerializer` that is really required to write nested `Event` objects.

Here's the `RaceSerializer`:

```
class RaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    type = TypeField()
    country = CountryField()
    region = RegionField()
    timezone = TimezoneField()
    events = EventSerializer(many=True)
    race_cal_types = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        with transaction.atomic():
            events = validated_data.pop('events', None)
            race = Race(**validated_data)
            race.save()
            for event in events:
                Event.objects.create(race=race, **event)
        return race
```

And here is the combo of `RelatedField` and `ModelSerializer` I'm using for each field in my `RaceSerializer`, e.g. for the `region` foreign key:

```
class RegionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = ('pk', 'name', 'code')


class RegionField(RelatedField):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Region.objects.all()

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return self.get_queryset().get(**data)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return RegionSerializer(value).data
```

Each field (`type`, `region`, `country`, `timezone`) has its own `to_internal_value` and `to_representation` methods to serializer/deserialize data the way I need to.

Comment: Why are you not sending just the ids of the objects that you are trying to link. And is there any way we either create or use existing object if non exists and data is available.

Comment: @SardarFaisal If you want to write new objects, you need to use Serializers instead of RelatedField objects. I've found RelatedField to be a better choice than a Serializer when needing to reference read-only related objects.